Consolidate Word Tables with VBA
The attached Word document contains tables (this is a demo, in reality there will be an undefined amount of tables with undefined amount of rows).
I want to consolidate all of them to a single table at the end of the document.
Furthermore the heading row should only appear once.
Now it looks like this:

Should look in the end like this:

Sub waldenwald()

Sub walde()

    Dim t As Table, r As Row
    Dim i As Integer
  
    For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each r In t.Rows
            If r.Index > 1 Then
                For i = 1 To 5

                    ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Range.Copy
    
                    Set range2 = ActiveDocument.Content
                    range2.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                    range2.Paste
    
                Next i
            End If
        Next r
    Next t

End Sub


Sub kopierensuperlean()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 5

    ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Range.Copy
    
    Set range2 = ActiveDocument.Content
    range2.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    range2.Paste
    
Next i

End Sub


Welcome to SO.
Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

Microsoft documentation:

Range.Text property (Word)


Range.End property (Word)


Tables.Add method (Word)

Option 1:

Copy over the first table with the header to the end, and then copy other tables without header

Sub ConsolidateTablesCopyPaste()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim mainTable As Table
    Dim tbl As Table, tblRange As Range
    Dim row As row, iCount As Long, iEnd As Long
    Dim colCount As Integer
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim mergedTable As Table
    
    ' Set the document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    iCount = doc.Tables.Count
    ' Check if there are any tables in the document
    If iCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No tables found in the document."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Insert a newline if doc is end with a table
    iEnd = doc.Content.End - 2
    If doc.Range(iEnd, iEnd).Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        doc.Characters.Last.InsertAfter vbCr
    End If
    
    ' Iterate through each table and copy the rows (except header row)
    For k = 1 To iCount
        Set tbl = doc.Tables(k)
        Set tblRange = tbl.Range.Duplicate
        If k > 1 Then
            tblRange.Start = tbl.Rows(2).Range.Start
        End If
        tblRange.Copy
        doc.Characters.Last.Paste
    Next k
End Sub


Option 2:

Insert a new table first, then copy cells' content one by one


Sub ConsolidateTables()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim mainTable As Table
    Dim tbl As Table, iCount As Long, iEnd As Long
    Dim row As row, sTxt As String
    Dim colCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Long
    Dim mergedTable As Table

    ' Set the document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    iCount = doc.Tables.Count
    ' Check if there are any tables in the document
    If iCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No tables found in the document."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Create a new table at the end of the document
    colCount = doc.Tables(1).Columns.Count
    iEnd = doc.Content.End - 1
    If doc.Range(iEnd - 1, iEnd - 1).Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        doc.Characters.Last.InsertAfter vbCr
        iEnd = iEnd + 1
    End If
    Set mergedTable = doc.Tables.Add(Range:=doc.Range(iEnd, iEnd), NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=colCount)
    
    ' Copy the header row from the first table
    For i = 1 To colCount
        sTxt = doc.Tables(1).Cell(1, i).Range.Text
        mergedTable.Cell(1, i).Range.Text = Left(sTxt, Len(sTxt) - 2)
    Next i
    
    ' Append rows from all tables
    For k = 1 To iCount
        Set tbl = doc.Tables(k)
        ' Skip the header row
        For i = 2 To tbl.Rows.Count
            ' Add a new row to the merged table
            Set row = mergedTable.Rows.Add
            ' Copy each cell from the current row
            For j = 1 To colCount
                sTxt = tbl.Cell(i, j).Range.Text
                row.Cells(j).Range.Text = Left(sTxt, Len(sTxt) - 2)
            Next j
        Next i
    Next k
    mergedTable.Style = "List Table 3 - Accent 1" ' modify as needed
End Sub




Wow, you are a hero, many thanks to you!!! :)
Just one thing: if I wanted to insert the Table e.g. after the Header 6, how would I change the code?
Thanks in advance and kind regards,

What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?
What should I do when someone answers my question?
